# Express tree structure using Thrift

Tags: tree, thrift

I'm now using Thrift as protocol for communication.
I have to pass an object (Tree data structure) to map with Tree data structure. I want to generate java code.
How can I transfer a tree data-structure via Thrift, I defined an object by Tree but thrift doesn't allow this way, a piece from my thrift file:

```
struct MyObject {
1:i32 id,
2:i32 parentid,
3:string name,
4:list<MyObject> children
}
```

However, I got this error from Thrift: Type "MyObject" has not been defined.
Is there any walkaround for this? 
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

You can try this.

```
struct TreeNode {
1:i32 id,
2:i32 parentid,
3:string name,
4:list<i32> childrenIds
}

struct Tree {
1:i32 rootId,
2:map<i32,TreeNode> nodes,
}
```

Using this way you have simple data structure that can be interpreted as a tree

Answer (score 1):

Thrift doesn't allow recursion:
http://grokbase.com/t/thrift/user/0984cqwxen/recursive-datatypes
The possible workaround was written by user537862